# d3.js force diagram: collapse parent children to tidy up path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, force-layout

I'm using d3.js for a force diagram and was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem I have? I'd like to hide the parent children as the user clicks down through a branch if that makes sense... tricky to explain so I made a quick sketch:

[image]

The green node is the root, and the red nodes have children but are closed because there is an open option further down the branch.

I hope that makes sense! Is this behaviour possible?

Comment: Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130)?

Comment: Hi Lars, sort of but not quite... as you click down through a branch, the parent node children should collapse.

Comment: Ok, so you would have to trigger this in your code rather than through user interaction. The example should get you started though.